# How do I get "expect" to toggle in and out of interactive mode?

Tags: expect

I am writing my first expect script to run a gvfs-mount.  I'd like the expect wcript to answer the prompts down to "Password: " allow me to enter the password, then switch back to non-interactive mode to finish up.

I wish to modify this script generated by autoexpect and slightly depersonalized by me:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout -1
spawn gvfs-mount {smb://my-userid@10.253.x.y/my-userid$}
match_max 100000
expect -exact "Password required for share my-userid\$ on 10.253.x.y\r\nDomain \[WORKGROUP\]: "
send -- "my-domain\r"
expect -exact "my-domain\r\nPassword: "
send -- "my-password\r"
expect eof
```

Just changing -exact to -i in the second send puts the whole script into a state where it waits for me to input the domain but doesn't read the keyboard or"send".  I speculate that has to do with having gvfs-mount spawned in a background process not tied to the foreground stdin.

So how do I toggle the interactivity of some "expects"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it. I stay out of interact and trick the user into thinking they're entering their password so I can store it in a variable.

```
expect "*?assword:*" {
  stty -echo
  if {[string length $lpass] < 1} {
    expect_user {
      -re "(.*)\n" {set lpass "$expect_out(1,string)"}
      timeout {exp_continue}
    }
  }
  send -- "$lpass\r"
}
stty echo
```

You can also jump into and out of interacts by putting a return inside the block like this:

```
interact -nobuffer -re "goodbye\r" {
  return
}
send_user -- "you're no longer interacting with the spawned process\n"
```

This will exit the interact statement when a user types in goodbye and hits enter.

Comment: You probably want to `stty -echo` before getting the user to type the password (and then of course `stty echo` afterwards)